# Analogue of Temperley-Lieb algebra of higher rank

Tags: graph-theory, representation-theory, gauge-theory, topological-quantum-field-theory

In Piunikhin’s *Turaev-Viro and Kauffman invariants for 3-manifolds coincide*, the exact relation between Kauffman algebra and the representation of the quantum group $U_q(sl_2)$ is shown.

This seems to be a coincidence due to low rank $n=2$, because all irreducible representations can be obtained as symmetric products of the lowest nontrivial one, which is not the case for higher $n$. Also, the smallest nontrivial one is small enough to impose Kauffman bracket relation!

What then is an analogue of TL-algebra that corresponds to the representations of $U_q(sl_n)$?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of references. [Here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0701045) is a paper by Sussan on link invariants associated to $sl_k$. Another pair of papers [(a)](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0701194) & [(b)](https://arxiv.org/abs/0710.3216) by Cautis-Kamnitzer also work on this problem.

More recent approaches using the idea of "categorification" are described by [Lauda](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.2128), see results by [Khovanov-Lauda](https://arxiv.org/abs/0807.3250) (and references therein) and this paper by [Webster](https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.3796).